# Access mysql from perl using odbc

Tags: mysql, macos, perl, odbc

I need to access MySQL from perl.

**Can I connect using the `odbc` driver?**

**If so, how do I do that?**

I just can't seem to get the connection string right!

On windows, where `DBD:MySQL` is available, this is how I connected:

```
DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$database", 
    $user, $password, {RaiseError => 1});
```

This is what I've tried:

```
DBI->connect("DBI:ODBC:$database", $user, $password, {RaiseError => 1});'
```

This results in the following error:

> DBI connect('database','username',...) failed: [iODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified. Driver could not be loaded (SQL-IM002) at -e line 1

This is a standard connection on a local machine -- that is, both the perl app and the MySQL server are on the same machine.

---

I'd like to use `odbc` because `DBD:mysql` [doesn't build](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/DBD-mysql/) for ActiveState perl on Mac OS X, and it's much easier for us when we stick with packages that can be obtained through ppm.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried including the port?

http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#p0cs1

Also, for ODBC you might need to specify the driver, if you're not going against a 
previously set up DSN

```
DBI->connect( join( ';'
    , 'DBI:ODBC:driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}'
    , "Server=$SQL_SERVER"
    , "Database=$SQL_DATABASE"
    , "UID=$SQL_USERID"
    , "PWD=$SQL_PASSWD"
    ));
```

Comment: No, I haven't.  I'll try that.  I've updated the OP to show what I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Your $database is not a database it is a Data Source Name (DSN). 'dbi:ODBC:xxx' should be read as 'dbi:ODBC:DSN=xxx' and the iODBC driver manager will look for a DSN called 'xxx' in its config files. As you are on a mac there should be a data sources GUI app you can use to create DSNs or alternatively, you'll have to find iODBC's ini files and insert them yourself (iodbc.ini and iodbcinst.ini I think or perhaps without the 'i').

"Data source name not found and no default driver specified" normally means the xxx data source cannot be found in the ini files (there are user and system ones) however that trailing "Driver could not be loaded (SQL-IM002)" kind of suggests the mysql ODBC driver library could not be loaded and hence your DSN does exist but it points to either an invalid mysql ODBC driver lib or one which is broken. Here again the GUI app allows you to add/edit drivers or you'll need to find the iodbcinst.ini file and see what the Driver attribute points to for the mysql driver.